# How do I create a data frame using bias() results, then scatter plotting those results via ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I'm new here and am learning R. I am trying to create sample sales forecast bias analysis (with a scatter plot of the bias results/SKU) using actual sales vs forecast sales from four SKUs. I tried, but the search function but was not able to find an answer. Please and thank you for any community replies. "tidyverse" & "SimDesign" packages are installed.

**Questions**

1. Am I creating the data frame correctly using the bias() function results after I create my vectors and run the bias() function using those vectors?
2. How would I plot these four bias() results using ggplot? Would I use + geom_plot() to plot these four results on one scatter plot? Once I have the initial plot, I can focus on the aesthetics and labeling. I do not know what to call out for the y-axis in the ggplot as the bias() result is what would be used for the y-axis range.

Below we are loading our as = "Actual Sales" data and our fs = "Forecast Sales" data into R for a trailing 6 month period.Below we are loading our as = "Actual Sales" data and our fs = "Forecast Sales" data into R for a trailing 6 month period.

```
SKUA_as <- c(68.3, 70, 72.4, 71, 67, 70)
SKUA_fs <- c(67.9, 69, 71.5, 70, 67, 69)

SKUB_as <- c(150, 203, 137, 247, 116, 287) 
SKUB_fs <- c(200, 300, 150, 250, 150, 300) 

SKUC_as <- c(73.3 ,75 ,77.4 ,76 ,72 ,75) 
SKUC_fs <- c(67.9, 69, 71.5, 70, 67, 69) 

SKUD_as <- c(63.3 ,65 ,67.4 ,66 ,62 ,65) 
SKUD_fs <- c(67.9, 69, 71.5, 70, 67, 69)
```

We can then run the bias function per SKU and determine the bias, or level of inaccuracy of the forecast model for each SKU.

```
SKUA_bias <- bias(SKUA_as, SKUA_fs)
SKUB_bias <- bias(SKUB_as, SKUB_fs)
SKUC_bias <- bias(SKUC_as, SKUC_fs)
SKUD_bias <- bias(SKUD_as, SKUD_fs)
```

Now we need to create the data frame, called "sku_analysis" in R so that we can view the output of the bias functions/calculations for each SKU.

```
sku_analysis <- data.frame(SKUA_bias, SKUB_bias, SKUC_bias, SKUD_bias)
```

Now we can view the bias results.

```
str(sku_analysis)
```

### Visualizing the bias results

This is an example of an embeded plot:

```
ggplot(data=sku_analysis,aes(x= SKUA_bias, SKUB_bias, SKUC_bias, SKUD_bias))
```

**Answers**
The below links are me testing the answers and posting the results thus far.

[click this link to see plot generated from suggestion by @KacZdr > plot(sku_analysis)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi2UB.png)

Comment: `bias` function is correct, but how do you imagine the graph with 4 single variables? what would the axes be in this case? Try `plot(sku_analysis)`, this is what it looks like.

Comment: @KacZdr , I tried your suggestion and the following plot was still a difficult visualization to understand ... or at least it presents poorly. I will see if I can add that plot to my original inquiry so you can see what is generated. Thank you greatly for your time!